# How to instantiate an object of a class in a module that resides in a parent directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails for building api and I have the below directory structure

```
|-- api
|   |-- api_controller.rb
|   |-- v1
|   |   |-- login_controller.rb
|   |   |-- comp
|   |   |   |-- login
|   |   |   |   |-- clogin.rb
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   |   |-- session.rb
```

Here I try to access in the way login_controller -> clogin -> session .
From login_controller.rb I could access constant VA in clogin.rb using the below code

```
module API::V1
  class LoginController < API::ApiController
    def index
        require_relative 'comp/login/clogin'
        comp = Comp::Login::Clogin::VA
    end
  end
end
```

But from clogin.rb, I'm not able to access constant VB in session.rb.

clogin.rb :

```
require_relative '../../lib/session'
 module API::V1::Comp::Login
  class Clogin
   VA 
    def intialize()
     VA = Lib::Session::VB
    end
  end
end
```

session.rb :

```
module API::V1::Lib
 class Session
  VB
  def intialize()
    VB = "accessing Lib"
  end
 end
end
```

Few additional detail on why I'm maintaining such directory structure:

1. In rails api, I wanted to version my application library (lib directory)
2. I would maintain my app library outside the comp directory.

Also, let me know if there is an alternate way to achieve version-ing of my apps's library

Answer (score 1):

First, the method your trying to use is `initialize` not `intialize`. Second, it is called when an **instance** of your class is instantiated via `MyClass.new`. In your code, this would result in dynamic reassignment of a constant which will throw an exception.

You could do this instead:

```
module API::V1::Lib
  class Session
    VB = "accessing Lib"
  end
end

module API::V1::Comp::Login
  class Clogin
    VA = Lib::Session::VB
  end
end
```

You might also try adding your lib directory to your autoload paths (see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) so you don't need to do `require_relative` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

To add up to the above answer,a small change in clogin.rb was done.

session.rb

```
module API::V1::Lib
  class Session
   VB = "accessing Lib"
  end
end
```

clogin.rb

```
require_relative '../../lib/session'
module API::V1::Comp::Login
 class Clogin
  VA = API::V1::Lib::Session::VB
 end
end
```